# Error "ratlperl is not recognized as a internal or external command"

Tags: perl, web-services, environment-variables

Ran a Perl command "Perl pdi add2is -isdc 2/1095- -prodno "CXC 101 999/1" -rstate R1G09 -object ABC-115511 -objver A env -Accept

( which is used to access a web service) in cmd of windows, got error "ratlperl is not recognized as a internal or external command"

I had to login to the web services application before running any web service, which I am 100% sure is successfully logged in. I guess the problem is with my Environmental variables.. Kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, your question does not make any sense. Please [edit] and include at least the full command that you ran, and the full error message. On top of that, we might need to see the environment. It looks like it could be a simple typo, but what you have written in the question is incredibly unclear, so all we can do is make wild guesses. Please also take a moment to read the [faq] and take the [tour]. Thank you. :)

Comment: Thanks you. I found what the problem but I got another problem now. I might add another question.

Comment: When you do, try to be very specific. ;)

Comment: Sure :) i will try my best. Hope the admins here can bear with me till I improve :(

Comment: If by _admins_ you mean _moderators_, then there are none. You should really take a look at the [faq]. This is a community-moderated question and answer site. Other users vote on posts based on the quality and the usefulness for future readers. We can also vote to close a question if it is off-topic. The more you participate, the more reputation you get, and that gives you more privileges. We all want the quality of the site to be high. That's what sets us apart from old-fashioned forums. You don't need "hi" and "thank you", but good examples are very valuable. :)

Comment: Okay. I understand now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the PATH environmental variable. It has to pointed to System32 path of the local.